# Execute shell script from scala application

Tags: scala, process

I want to execute the `sh` file from Scala application.
Let's say I have `createPassword.sh` file and I need to invoke this `sh` file from Scala application and get the output back.

How can I achieve through scala application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do the trick if the script is in the current working directory (otherwise specify the full path of the script)

```
import sys.process._
val result = "./createPassword.sh" !!
```

`result` is then a String containing the standard output (and standard error)

EDIT: If you want to use `ProcessBuillder` from Java SE7, you can also use this in scala:

```
  import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}

  val p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","createPassword.sh")
  val p2 = p.start()
  val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()))

  var line:String = ""
  while ({line = br.readLine();  line!= null}) {
    println(line)
  }
```

Comment: probably should be `"./createPassword.sh" !!`

Comment: Thats true, But i neeed  uses sys.process and it should not block, once the result is available ,It should be Processed

Comment: May be similar to usage of run method under process builder

Comment: @sharathchandra If you have an idea on how to do it in Java with ProcessBuilder, then just do it the same way in scala (you can also use ProcessBuilder from scala sourcecode)

Comment: @sharathchandra I added an example with ProcessBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Given your dir has a script,

```
`val path = "./src/test/tests/Integration/"`

`val output = Process("sh test.sh", new File("path")).!!`
```