# How to execute BASH source command from scala 2.11?

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, scala, shell

How do I execute BASH 'source' command using scala 2.11?

```
import scala.sys.process.Process

object putFileToHDFS {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("""In class putFileToHDFS""");

    val tester = Process("source ./trial.sh").lineStream;
    tester.foreach(println)


  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute shell script from scala aplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129780/execute-shell-script-from-scala-aplication)

Comment: What does it even mean to "source" a bash script from Scala? Since Scala is by definition not bash, it obviously cannot "source" files with bash definitions. Unclear what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the equivalent of what `source` does.

```
import scala.sys.process._

              //send file contents to sh for interpretation
val tester = "/bin/cat /path/trial.sh".#|("/bin/sh").lineStream
```

Of course, things are much easier if `trial.sh` is executable.

```
val tester = "/bin/sh -c /path/trial.sh".lineStream
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to source the script file, since you only need to do that when you want to include a script from another one. All you need to do is run it:

```
Process("bash trial.sh").lineStream
```