# How to pass arguments to shell script from a scala application?

Tags: scala, shell

I have a Scala application which needs to call the shell script by passing some arguments to it.

I followed the below answer and I am able to call the shell script from scala app without passing any arguments. But I have no idea how to pass the arguments.

[Execute shell script from scala application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129780/execute-shell-script-from-scala-application)

```
object ScalaShell {

  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
    val output = Try("//Users//xxxxx//Scala-workbench//src//main//scala//HelloWorld.sh".!!) match {
      case Success(value) =>
        value
      case Failure(exception) =>
        s"Failed to run: " + exception.getMessage
    }
    print(output)
  }

}
```

**HelloWorld.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a comment!
echo Hello World
```

**Current Output:**

Hello World

**Expected Output:**

Hello World, arg1 arg2  (where arg1 and arg2 were passed from scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @goosefand's answer, I have also added how to receive the arguments which is passed from scala in the shell script.

**Scala:**

```
object ScalaShell {

  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
    val output = Try(Seq("//Users//xxxxx//Scala-workbench//src//main//scala//HelloWorld.sh", "arg1","arg2").!!) match {
      case Success(value) =>
        value
      case Failure(exception) =>
        s"Failed to run: " + exception.getMessage
    }
    print(output)
  }

}
```

**Shell Script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Processing files $1 $2
```

Output:

```
Hello world arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 3):

It is explained in great detail in [Scala docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/sys/process/index.html) but my favorite way is this:

```scala
List("echo", "-e", "This \nis \na \ntest").!!
```

simply call the `!!` method on a list where the first element is the script/command and the remaining elements are the args/options.